# Wine stopped working

Tags: kernel, wine, emulation

Wine worked yesterday, however I downloaded some updates to the kernel and since then when I try to run Wine, I get error messages.  I assume this is related to the kernel update.  Anyway to overcome this ?

Comment: What error messages? Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/534809/edit) your question and include these messages and information on anything you may have done to resolve it.